# How do I downgrade JDK?

Tags: jdk, downgrade

I installed JDK with the Ubuntu Software application which selected JDK-16.0.2, and I need to downgrade to version 11.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) which version of Ubuntu are you installing this on? (2) do you need OpenJDK or the Oracle JDK?

Comment: @matigo **OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64... I need OpenJDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options ahead of you:

1. You can uninstall JDK-16.0.2, then install OpenJDK 11 and have just that implementation on your system
2. You can install OpenJDK 11 and use `update-alternatives` to specify which version you want to be treated as default

This answer will focus on the second option, though you can modify it to work for the first.

0. Open a Terminal (if one is not already open) or SSH into the server you're installing Java onto
1. Install the default Java runtime. For Ubuntu 20.04, this is version 11.0.11:

   ```
   sudo apt install default-jre
   ```

   If you want to be absolutely certain of the version, you can also specify the version:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
   ```
2. Install the default Java Development Kit:

   ```
   sudo apt install default-jdk
   ```
3. Confirm the versions:

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   This should give you something like:

   ```
   openjdk version "11.0.11"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
   ```

   Also check the compiler:

   ```
   javac -version
   ```

   Which will give you something like:

   ```
   javac 11.0.11
   ```
4. Set version 11 as the default for the system:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```

   This will give you an output similar to:

   ```
   There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

     Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
     1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
   * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1091      manual mode

   Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
   ```

   You can also do this for the compiler with:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config javac
   ```
5. Confirm your `JAVA_HOME` variable is correct:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/environment
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor that you prefer. The use of `vi` here is more a force of habit than an endorsement.</sup>
   Locate the `JAVA_HOME` variable and ensure it's set correctly:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
   ```

   Reload your sources:

   ```
   source /etc/environment
   ```

   Verify the variable is set:

   ```
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   ```

   You should see:

   ```
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
   ```

That's all there is to it

Comment: Thank you! I wasted so many hours trying to set up my development environment for React Native and it's finally working. What a nightmare...